# Watching a Directory and sub directory for create, modify and Changes in java

Tags: java

I have written some code for detecting changes in  `C:/java/newfolder` it is working good.

This is the code:

```java
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.List;

public class DirectoryWatchExample {
  public static void testForDirectoryChange(Path myDir) {
    try {
      WatchService watcher = myDir.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
      myDir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
          StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE,
          StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

      WatchKey watckKey = watcher.take();

      List<WatchEvent<?>> events = watckKey.pollEvents();
      for (WatchEvent event : events) {
        if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE) {
          System.out.println("Created: " + event.context().toString());
        }
        if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE) {
          System.out.println("Delete: " + event.context().toString());
        }
        if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY) {
          System.out.println("Modify: " + event.context().toString());
        }
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path myDir = Paths.get("c:/java/newfolder/");
    // define a folder root
    testForDirectoryChange(myDir);
  }
}
```

now i'm watching only the directory itself. But i need to watch only all the sub directory.

for example: `c:/java/newfolder/folder1, c:/java/newfolder/folder2, c:/java/newfolder/folder3......etc`

I tried using this sub directory string in the example above:

> c:/java/newfolder/*..

I need to watch the all sub directory. Can you give me a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `Path` API, so take the following with a grain of salt.

You're registering one directory for monitoring, and will receive notifications whenever one of its direct descendants is modified / created / deleted.

The first thing you need to do is register all of its subdirectories for watching:

```
// Used to filter out non-directory files.
// This might need to filter '.' and '..' out, not sure whether they're returned.
public class DirectoryFilter implements FileFilter {
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory();
    }
}


// Add this at the end of your testForDirectoryChange method
for(File dir: myDir.toFile().listFiles(new DirectoryFilter())) {
    testForDirectoryChange(dir.toPath());
}
```

This will recursively explore your file structure and register every directory for watching.
Note that if your directory tree is too deep, recursion might not be an acceptable solution and you might need to 'iterify' it.

The second thing you need to do is, whenever you receive a directory creation event, not forget to register the new directory for monitoring.

That's how I'd do it anyway, but not having a valid Java 1.7 installation at hand, I can't test it. Do let me know if it works!

Answer (score 11):

What you want to do is register the `WatchService` recursively and continue to register it upon subsequent `ENTRY_CREATE` events. A complete example is provided by Oracle here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java

Normally I wouldn't place a post with a single link, however I doubt Oracle will be taking down a fairly basic tutorial and the answer is far too verbose. Just in case though, examples are easily found by searching for "java watchservice recursive".

Comment: I was skeptical, but it just works. Give it an input dir name and it will watch all sub directories as well. This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for posting the link.

Comment: I am too. It registers the new folder when it detect his creation. If some condition (server load, small file), I think it can miss a file created in the subfolder.

Comment: Sorry for necroposting, but it behaves just like Nereis hinted. The Oracle example does not behave deterministically. Try let it watch an empty directory and then copy a medium sized directory tree in it. Some of the files won't get noticed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I came with..

```
    final WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

    final SimpleFileVisitor<Path> fileVisitor = new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>(){
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
        {
            dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);

            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    };

    Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("/directory/to/monitor"), fileVisitor);
```

Answer (score -1):

So what you want is listing the files/subdirectories within a directory?
You can use:

```
File dir = new File("c:/java/newfolder/");
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
```

listFiles() gives you the Files in a directory or null it it's not a directory.

Then you can do:

```
for (File file: files){
     if (file.listFiles != null){
          //It's a subdirectory
          File [] subdirFiles = file.listfiles;
     }
}
```

Comment: hai Luis don't wont to list the files.i need to watch the sub directory.give me some solutions..

Comment: The subdirectories are also in the files array. Check my edit.