# Recursively monitor a directory and all sub directories in java

Tags: java, directory, subdirectory, jnotify

I need to monitor a given directory and all its sub directories for changes (Especially addition of files and directories).

My current code is as follows

```
Path watchFolder = Paths.get("D:/watch");
    WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    watchFolder.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
            watchFolder.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);
            watchFolder.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

    boolean valid = true;
    do {
        WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();

        for (WatchEvent event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
            WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
            if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(kind)) {
                String fileName = event.context().toString();
                System.out.println("File Created:" + fileName);
            }
        }
        valid = watchKey.reset();

    } while (valid);
```

This code is only able to monitor the parent directory changes. If I add a directory in the parent directory, it is able to fire the event. But, if I add a file inside sub-directory, it is not able detect.

FYI : I also tried JNotify, but it keeps saying `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnotify_64bit in java.library.path`

Is there any better solution than these?

Comment: I think this has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850940/watching-a-directory-and-sub-directory-for-create-modify-and-changes-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I would like to encourage you to give [jnotify](/questions/tagged/jnotify) another try. It nicely reports changes in subdirectories and looks more resource efficient than creating a load of `WatchKey`s for each and every directory you want to track.

As for your `UnsatisfiedLinkError`, see [How to set the java.library.path from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700). I placed `jnotify_64bit.dll` (Windows here) in my project's base dir, and it worked. YMMV.

Answer (score -1):

From your question, I assume that your requirement is to poll the directory and when some file comes do something, meaning call some method.

If I have understood correctly then you should try [JPoller](http://jpoller.sourceforge.net/) which reduces the complexity and does what you need. It also allows you to set polling interval and provides you with a handful of callback methods.