# WatchService File overwritten notification

Tags: java

I want to get notification when a file is being overwritten in a folder. For ex: I have a file A.JSON in a folder. When I overwrite the same file (A.JSON) in the same path, i want to get notification.

I have tried WatchService sample as per below link.

https://kodejava.org/how-to-monitor-file-or-directory-changes/

```
    // I kept a file called A.JSON in this path
    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/Users/XYZ/MyProjectWorkspace/MyTestProject/src");

    try {
                    Boolean isFolder = (Boolean) Files.getAttribute(path,
                            "basic:isDirectory", NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
                    if (!isFolder) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Path: " + path + " is not a folder");
                    }
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    // Folder does not exists
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }


    System.out.println("Watching path: " + path);
                // We obtain the file system of the Path
                FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem ();

                // We create the new WatchService using the new try() block
                try(WatchService service = fs.newWatchService()) {

                    // We register the path to the service
                    // We watch for creation events
                    path.register(service, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_DELETE);


                    // Start the infinite polling loop
                    WatchKey key = null;
                    while(true) {
                        key = service.take();

                        // Dequeueing events
                        Kind<?> kind = null;
                        for(WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : key.pollEvents()) {

                            /*final Path changed = (Path) watchEvent.context();
                            System.out.println(changed);
                            if (changed.endsWith("A.json")) {
                                System.out.println("My file has changed");
                            }
                            */

                            // Get the type of the event
                            kind = watchEvent.kind();
                            if (OVERFLOW == kind) {
                                continue; //loop
                            } else if (ENTRY_CREATE == kind) {
                                // A new Path was created 
                                //Path newPath = ((WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent).context();
                                // Output
                                //System.out.println("New path created: " + newPath);
                                System.out.println("New path created");
                            } else if (ENTRY_MODIFY == kind) {
                                // A new Path was created 
                                //Path newPath = ((WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent).context();
                                // Output
                                //System.out.println("New path created: " + newPath);
                                System.out.println("Modified");
                            }
                        }

                        if(!key.reset()) {
                            break; //loop
                        }
                    }

                } catch(IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }
```

It works when the new folder created or modified etc. But, I want to be notified when a same file is being overwritten in a folder.

Please advise me how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Watching a Directory and sub directory for create, modify and Changes in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850940/watching-a-directory-and-sub-directory-for-create-modify-and-changes-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The watch service looks for changes in that directory, only.  If you create a folder in the directory, you will be told of the folder's creation.  If you create a file in that new folder, you may be notified that the folder *in your watched directory* was modified; you will not be told of the files or folders added, modified, or removed inside folders inside of your watched directory.  To do that, you would need to watch those subfolders as well.

---

I replaced your `if` statements with the following one:

```
if (kind == ENTRY_CREATE || kind == ENTRY_MODIFY || kind == ENTRY_DELETE) {
    Path newPath = ((WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent).context();
    System.out.println(kind + ": "+newPath+"  ");
}
```

Then I ran the code, created, modified, and deleted an "A.json" file in the watched directory.  Then I created a "subfolder" and "subsubfolders" within it, where I created, modified, and deleted "A.json" in each.  I received this output:

> Watching path: /Users/aneufeld/workspaces/olan/StackOverflow/src/stackoverflow
>   ENTRY_CREATE: A.json
>   ENTRY_MODIFY: A.json
>   ENTRY_DELETE: A.json
>   ENTRY_CREATE: subfolder
>   ENTRY_MODIFY: subfolder
>   ENTRY_MODIFY: subfolder
>   ENTRY_MODIFY: subfolder
>   ENTRY_DELETE: subfolder

As you can see, the watch service correctly reports creations, modifications and deletions in the watched directory only.  A folder in the watched directory may be flagged as modified when entries inside the folder are added or removed, but no indication is given as to what the modification was is provided.  Changes inside sub-sub-folders are completely silent.

---

To watch all subfolders from your starting path, instead of

```
path.register(service, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_DELETE);
```

you could use:

```
Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        dir.register(service, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_DELETE);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```

This will only register folders that already exist rooted at `path`.  If a new folder is created, you will simply receive an `ENTRY_CREATE` event.  You would have to determine the entry was a directory, and proceed to register it as well.  You may have to watch for `ENTRY_DELETE` events and deregister paths from the watch service if they are removed.  Exercise left to student.